# Comparing floating point numbers with numpy and scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is there any epsilon constant (as in Matlab) in numpy or scipy modules to compare floating point numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [np.finfo](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.finfo.html)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.finfo(np.double).eps
2.2204460492503131e-16
>>> np.finfo(np.single).eps
1.1920929e-07
```