# Numpy.where function not finding values within array... Anyone know why?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, where-clause

I have been trying to use python's `numpy.where` function to determine the location of a specific value, but for some reason it incorrectly determines `False` where the value is actually found. Thereby returning an empty array. See below:

```
>>>lbpoly=numpy.array([ 5.45  5.5   5.55  5.6   5.65  5.7   5.75  5.8   5.85  5.9   5.95  6.
6.05  6.1   6.15  6.2   6.25  6.3   6.35  6.4   6.45  6.5   6.55  6.6
6.65  6.7   6.75  6.8   6.85  6.9   6.95  7.  ])

>>>cpah=numpy.where(lbpoly==6.2)

>>>print cpah

>>>(array([], dtype=int32),)
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I've tried many different variants, even using `<` and `>` logic. But this produces indices for 2 values.

Comment: is your `lbpoly` a numpy-array? Looks like a list.

Comment: A list displays with commas, numpy arrays without (usually).

Comment: @dede Yes, it's an array. In my haste I incorrectly placed it here to look like a list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is very little meaning in comparing floating point numbers; in particular, there is a lot you cannot learn by observing the printed representation of floating point numbers. (See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212210/comparing-floating-point-numbers-with-numpy-and-scipy).)

Try something like this:

```
import numpy as np

lbpoly= np.array([4.0, 6.2])

>>> np.where(np.isclose(lbpoly, 6.2))
(array([1]),)
```